# Windows XP netbook displaying only one time zone

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-registry, netbook, time-zone

We just returned from Spain and one of our computers will absolutely not change or even display time zones other the that of Madrid.

I looked up some solutions online, but they all involved doing some reg editing, so I´m looking for some input.

What do I do to be able to view and use other time zones?

Comment: This is kind of hard to understand without a picture. Do you think you can post a screenshot or screencast of what happens when you try to change the timezone?

Comment: When I try and change the timezone, all that happens in the drop down menu has only one time zone, instead of multiple